# Linq to Twitter Authenticated But Getting 215 "Bad Authentication Data"

Tags: twitter, json.net, linq-to-twitter

I have been using Linq to Twitter for Authenticating with OAuth for the Twitter API 1.1. 
I set my credentials and then pass them to Linq to Twitter which states I that isAuth returns true. However, at run time I receive at 215 "Bad Authentication Data" error. Has anyone else had this problem?

```
  var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
            {
                ConsumerKey = TwitterSettings.ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = TwitterSettings.ConsumerKeySecret,
                OAuthToken = TwitterSettings.AccessToken,
                AccessToken = TwitterSettings.AccessTokenSecret,
            }
        };
        auth.Authorize();
    }
```

And here is the if else that is stating I am authorized:

```
        if (auth == null || !auth.IsAuthorized)
        {

        }
        // If Twitter Authorizes Application 
        if (auth.IsAuthorized && i == 1)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4"));
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            var jsonResults = obj["results"];

            await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<List<Tweet>>(jsonResults.ToString());

        }
```

I am able to get into the auth.IsAtuhorized portion of the code but the response is returning a 215 error. Also I know my URI is correct because I copied it straight from the Twitter API 1.1 example page to test the call. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the authorizer properly, but then you aren't using LINQ to Twitter to make your query. You're using HttpClient instead and there isn't a relationship between the two APIs. Here's a example of how to perform a Search with LINQ to Twitter:

```
    var srch =
        (from search in twitterCtx.Search
         where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
               search.Query == "LINQ to Twitter" &&
               search.Count == 7
         select search)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery: {0}\n", srch.SearchMetaData.Query);
    srch.Statuses.ForEach(entry =>
        Console.WriteLine(
            "ID: {0, -15}, Source: {1}\nContent: {2}\n",
            entry.StatusID, entry.Source, entry.Text));
```

You can visit the [LINQ to Twitter Search Documentation](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Searching%20Twitter&referringTitle=Performing%20Searches%20and%20Finding%20Trends) for more info on available parameters.

**Update**, Here's an asynchronous sample:

```
    (from search in twitterCtx.Search
     where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
           search.Query == QueryTextBox.Text
     select search)
    .MaterializedAsyncCallback(asyncResponse =>
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (asyncResponse.Status != TwitterErrorStatus.Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error during query: " + asyncResponse.Exception.Message);
                return;
            }

            Search search = asyncResponse.State.SingleOrDefault();
            var tweets =
                (from status in search.Statuses
                 select new Tweet
                 {
                     UserName = status.User.Identifier.ScreenName,
                     Message = status.Text,
                     ImageSource = status.User.ProfileImageUrl
                 })
                .ToList();

            SearchListBox.ItemsSource = tweets;
        }));
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. One more  question though rather than writing the results the console using Write line I am trying to add them to a list. I've tried using the basic Foreach Loop and your srch.Statues.Foreach method but it keeps saying it does not contain a method for 'ForEach'

Comment: Never Mind was able to do a work around by performing a basic For Loop thanks for your help. Will Post the finished answer upon code completion

Comment: Joe. One more question is there anyway to use async and await with the search function to increase performance?

Comment: Dadles, I did an update to the post to show the asynchronous syntax that's available today. That said, async is something I'm looking at for a future set of enhancements.